# Problema com char array para descobrir se o input é vogal, consoante e maiúscula ou minúscula

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando fazer com que o usuário digite um símbolo no *input* e o programa reconheça se o símbolo digitado foi uma vogal, vogal maiúscula, consoante, consoante maiúscula ou outro caractere.

Para isso estou comparando uma *string input* com os *arrays* preenchidos com as determinadas vogais, consoantes, etc, porém o *prompt* executa até o *input*, e assim que eu insiro ele fecha, provavelmente estou errando nas sintaxes pois não conheço muito bem a linguagem C.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'},

upperVowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'},

consonants[] = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'},

upperConsonants[] = {'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'},

input;

    printf("Enter the symbol:\n");
    scanf("%c",&input);

    if (strcmp(input, vowels) == 0){
        printf("vowels!");
    } else if (strcmp(input, upperVowels) == 0){
        printf("Upper vowels!");
    } else if (strcmp(input, consonants) == 0){
        printf("Consonants!");
    } else if (strcmp(input, upperConsonants) == 0){
        printf("Upper Consonants!");
    } else {
        printf("You entered another character!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em suas definições de vowels, upperVowels, consonants e upperConsonants você não definiu strings mas sim um array de caracteres (uma string é um array de caracteres com o terminador '\0') e portanto não pode utilizar as função de <string.h> da forma como fez. Além disso sua variável input está definida como um único caractere.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas aí, um deles é o uso da função errada e outro é o fato de não ter criado *strings* e sim *arrays* de `chars`s sem um terminador, por isso não são *strings*. Se você quer saber da existência de um caractere em uma *string* então deve usar [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr). Esta função retorna a posição (endereço) de onde tem o caractere ou um nulo se não achar nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char input, vowels[] = "aeiou", upperVowels[] = "AEIOU", consonants[] = "bcdfghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz", upperConsonants[] = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    printf("Enter the symbol: ");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (strchr(vowels, input) != 0) printf("vowels!");
    else if (strchr(upperVowels, input) != 0) printf("Upper vowels!");
    else if (strchr(consonants, input) != 0) printf("Consonants!");
    else if (strchr(upperConsonants, input) != 0) printf("Upper Consonants!");
    else printf("You entered another character!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vJKKzN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/IsVowelc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/IsVowel.c).

Comment: Cara tu me ajudou demais, serio mesmo, muito obrigado!!!